# Python: Calculating positive root of a quadratic equation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning the Python tutorial on MIT, and I'm having a problem with one of the exercises. The exercise is,

> Use the IPython prompt to calculate:
>
> Positive root of the following equation: 34x2 + 68x - 510 = 0 Recall:
>   given ax2 + bx + c = 0 , then x = (-b +sqrt(b*b - 4ac))/(2*a)

I have entered

> (-68)+(math.sqrt((68**2)-(4*34*510)))

in the iprompt, and I'm getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>   (-68)+(math.sqrt((68**2)-(434510)))
>
> ValueError: math domain error

On calculating individually, I found that the value inside the square root is negative. Should I be adding some additional functions to enable negative root calculation, or is there something else that is wrong with my statement?

Can someone help me out?

Note: The solutions on the course page suggest making

> (b**2-4ac)

positive before calculating the root. Will this not be mathematically inaccurate?

Answer (score 1):

I am taking the same course, I did this way and got the right answers. Write the equation like this:

```
(-68+((68**2)-4*34*(-510))**0.5)/(2*34)
```

That will give you the 1st solution, just change the sign of plus to minus and you get the 2nd solution, as:

```
(-68-((68**2)-4*34*(-510))**0.5)/(2*34)
```

Check the photo I have attached, it is a screenshot of the solutions.

[Screenshot of Spyder solving equation 34x^2+68x-510](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBbJC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let `f(x) = ax² + bx + c`. If you want to solve `f(x) = 0` in the field of *real* numbers, then you need to take care of the discriminant of `f` defined to be `b² - 4ac`. If the latter is negative, you do not have real solutions (and to have solutions you need to consider `f` as a complex polynomial, meaning that you want to find a solution to `f(x) = 0` in the field of *complex* numbers).

Now, for your problem, it appears that you have a sign problem. The coefficient `c` is equal to `-510` and not `510`. Thus, `68² - 4*34*510` should be `68² - 4*34*(-510) = 68² + 4 * 34 * 510`.

Answer (score 0):

if f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c then its positive root will be

( -b + sqrt (b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a

According to your Question f(x) = 34x^2 + 68x - 510 = 0

So +ve root will be =>  ( -68 + sqrt (68^2 - 4*34*(-510)) ) / (2*34) = 3

In python code will be like -

```
from math import sqrt

print((-68 + sqrt(68**2 - 4*34*(-510)))/(2*34))
```

But what you did wrong is, you have taken co-efficient of 'C' is 510.

Instead It should be (-510).

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the course as well. 

The question is from "getting started", so it shouldn't be hard.

And it should be related to the course material.

Therefore, here is what I have:

```
IDLE 1.2.4      
>>> import math
>>> a=34
>>> b=68
>>> c=-510
>>> d = ( -b + math.sqrt ( b*b - 4*a*c))/(2 * a)
>>> print d
3.0
```